# Can a website use webhooks?

Tags: webhooks, openapi

Ok, this may be super-simple, but I just don't have enough background knowledge to know for sure:

If I define a webhook callback (fer example, a callback in OpenAPI):  can I use that callback from a regular webpage?

I would assume yes, otherwise whats the point: but all the discussions state:

```
Must be network accessible by the source server
```

AFAIK: the clients browser is very unlikely to be accessible from the browser.  Which would make webhooks unusable for a hosted website.  Is this correct?

Comment: A webhook/callback is a request that a third-party server sends to an URL that you specify (e.g. a POST request to `https://mysite.example.com/webhook-test`). Or if you develop a service with callback, your service needs to send a request to an URL provided by a client (i.e. you need to POST to `https://clients-site.example.com/webhook-test`). There's no browser involved (unless I misunderstand your use case).

Comment: Yeah, I probably used all the wrong terrms.  I just want to push updates to clients (avoid polling) and hoped that this feature of OpenAPI would enable it.

Comment: Here's some resources that might help with what you are trying to do: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSub     https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events   or alternatively you could use websockets

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not really sure what you are asking. A web hook is simply a web script called by a service, its a Url that can be called by a web browser as well.

```
http://www.example.com/webhook.php?value=1&another=2
```

You can call this from OpenAPI, or by simply typing it into a browser window.

In `webhook.php`, you would look for `value` and `another`. Depending on if the callback is a POST, you would do `$value = $_POST['value'];`.

Not really sure what you mean by **"the clients browser is very unlikely to be accessible from the browser**".

Comment: Perhaps I am using the wrong terminology.  I would like clients on my webpage to receive callbacks from the server in response to long-running jobs.  As I understand it, I can supply a callback URL to OpenAPI endpoints with a callback tag - however, what URL would the client supply?  Wouldn't any attempts for the server to contact the client be rejected?

Comment: Why would the client provide any callback Url? Your server should provide the data (which interns should have received some api call back).

Comment: You would do the long running process on your server, then you could provide some kind of user notification (push perhaps).

Comment: So from the sounds of it, I can't use callbacks/webhooks (and by extension, OpenAPI) to send notifications to the client of progress...  thanks for the clarification, I just assumed that was the goal of the feature, I just couldn't figure out how it might work